# Changing limits of integration in trig

Tags: calculus

I don't know why but I decided to solve this very easy integral by substituting $\sin x=t$
$$\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}xdx=\int_{x=\pi/3}^{x=2\pi/3}\frac{\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$
Since for $x=2\pi/3$ and $x=\pi/3$, $t=\sqrt{3}/2$,
$$\int_{\sqrt{3}/2}^{\sqrt{3}/2}\frac{\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$
which, since each side of the limit is same, shoud be $0$, which obviously is not the answer.

What went wrong?

Comment: The substitution is inadmisible since $\;\sin x\;$ is **not** $\;1-1\;$ on $\;\left[\frac\pi3,\,\frac{2\pi}3\right]\;$ .

Comment: Then how should I substitute a variable to a trig in such case? Is it just impossible?

Comment: You can try $x = \arccos t$ (which is also $\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin t$)

Comment: $$ 0<\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\,dx \stackrel{x^2\mapsto u}{=} \int_{1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{u}\,du}{2}=0.$$ What went wrong? Well, $x^2\mapsto u$ is an allowed substitution only if $x^2$ is monotonic on the integration range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that the range of $\arcsin t$ is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

To fix you should set

$$\sin \left(x-\frac{\pi}2\right)=t \implies x=\arcsin t + \frac{\pi}2$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\text{arcsin}(t)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ has no solutions!

Arcsin is defined to be the inverse function of $\sin(t)$ on the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. The equation $\text{arcsin}(t)=a$ has solution only if $-\pi/2\le a\le\pi/2$